# What is the recommended way to define numeric function with special cases?

Tags: function-construction, guidelines

What is the recommended way to define a purely numeric function with special cases?  Should I define many special cases with pattern matching?

```
(*TOY EXAMPLE*)
f[a_,b_]/;a>b := Sin[a-b];
f[a_,b_]/;a<b := Tan[a/b];
f[a_,b_]/;a==b := Cos[a+b];
```

or should I use `Piecewise`?

```
f[a_,b_] := Piecewise[{{Sin[a-b],a>b},{Tan[a/b],a<b},{Cos[a+b],a==b}}]
```

or should I use `UnitStep`?  How about `If` statements?

**Also** What about if the function is continuous across each segments (not like the toy example above)?  and if the function is smooth?

Comment: I gave a brief answer below with my own opinions.  Later I shall try to add examples to support my statements if someone has not already provided a better answer by that time.

Comment: Use `PieceWise`, `UnitStep` and friends, if you want your function to integrate well with mathematical functionality such as simplifications, etc. Otherwise use rules. The `If` is inferior to both of those ways, in most cases.

Comment: @Leonid I forgot about that benefit of `Piecewise`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Do you really think `If` is inferior when it concerns purely numeric functions? I wonder why that would be the case. Of course it's not usually equally aesthetic, but is there another reason you're thinking about? I guess the question doesn't really define the functions as *purely* numeric, so you're right if one admits that symbolic simplifications could still be performed. Thinking about it, it would be best if the question were made more specific.

Comment: @Jens Two reasons: it makes the code harder to extend (and actually, harder to read) and more error-prone when there are several branches (you would need nested `If` or `Which`), and also it tends to be somewhat slower (not by much). But, I'd agree that this is largely a matter of taste. Philosophically, the closer you are to the core language constructs, the better, and patterns / rules are certainly closer to the core than the `If`/`Which` statements, because the core of Mathematica is a term-rewriting engine.

Comment: I really think the question needs to be made more precise. First of all, the definitions in the example are contradictory. Second, what do you want to do with the function?

Comment: `If/Which` and conditional pattern methods will not be handled well by either the algebra (`Solve` family) or calculus (continuous and discrete) functions.

Comment: @Jens thanks for pointing out the contraction.  It is fixed.   Also, the main use of the function is to carry out `NIntegrate`, to `Plot` and for carrying out statistical analysis (fitting functions involving `f` to data, etc..)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and @Daniel Thanks for explanation! I would by default also prefer `Piecewise`, but was thinking there must also be examples where `If` could be better (e.g. if one really *wants* to prevent even symbolic evaluation of one alternative under all circumstances).

Comment: @QuantumDot FYI-- From [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NIntegrate.html): "NIntegrate symbolically analyzes its input to transform oscillatory and other integrands, subdivide piecewise functions, and select optimal algorithms." From [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Plot.html): "Use automatic methods for computing exclusions, in this case for a piecewise function:..." `UnitStep` is vectorized and efficient on packed arrays, which may not apply to your use-cases. Finally, there's `PIecewiseExpand`, which can convert `If`, `Which`, and `UnitStep` to `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From testing in version 7, which I have not yet repeated in version 10, I recommend that you use your first form, as I found it to have at least a small performance advantage over `Piecewise` etc.  I also find it very readable.

If you can reformulate your function for application to vectors then the use of `UnitStep` etc., where possible without being overly contrived, may be considerably faster.  I see that as a special optimization technique however, not a matter of standard practice.

One place that `Piecewise`, `Switch` etc. can be easier to use is if you wish to programmatically manipulate the function.

Regarding **Also** I think I need an example of what you mean by "continuous across each segments."

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd also use `Piecewise` because it's clearest.

*However*, to play devil's advocate, here is an example of where `Piecewise` is not the best choice (at least in *Mathematica* version 10.0.0):

```
Plot[
 Piecewise[{{Sin[x], {x, 0} ∈ 
     ImplicitRegion[-1 < x < 1, {x, y}]}, {1, True}}], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: bug]

The warning here seems to be due to the fact that `Piecewise` holds all its arguments and then analyzes the conditions in a form that has not been fully evaluated. At that stage it doesn't recognize the new region functionality and spits out the warning. Fortunately, the rest of the calculation is correct, but clearly the warning is incorrect. This is most likely a bug in `Plot` (**and appears to have been fixed in version 10.0.1** on Mac as per Michael's comment below), and it can be circumvented by using `If` because the condition in `If` is *not* held unevaluated:

```
Plot[
 If[{x, 0} ∈ ImplicitRegion[-1 < x < 1, {x, y}], Sin[x], 
  1], {x, -2, 2}]
```

With this you get the same plot but no warnings.

Here the difference is that `If` has attribute `HoldRest` whereas `Piecewise` has attribute `HoldAll`, which we don't want.

Assuming this bug will get fixed, the fact remains that the different `Hold...` attributes of `If` may in certain cases make it the more natural choice, compared to `Piecewise`. If that happens, the choice would be more between `If` and  pattern-based alternatives. Then the decision could still depend on other details, such as whether you intend to `Compile` the function.

Comment: The first example, http://i.stack.imgur.com/LUovE.png, works in V10.0.1, Mac OS 10.9.5.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Interesting. The plot generated also looks different.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, I added that info.

Comment: Actually, it is not fixed in **Windows**. I'm also using **V10.0.1**.

Comment: @RunnyKine OK thanks, I edited that in as well...

Comment: @RunnyKine How odd.  I wonder how that would depend on system stuff -- GPU?  I assume the plot looks different because `Exclusions` has been fixed (in the Mac version).  I would have thought that was a *Mathematica* programming bug, not a system bug.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm perplexed by it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)

```
f[a_,b_]/;a>b := Sin[a-b];
f[a_,b_]/;a<b := Tan[a/b];
f[a_,b_]/;a==b := Cos[a+b];
```

Option 2 : [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[a_,b_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {Sin[a-b], a>b}, 
    {Tan[a/b], a<b},
    {Cos[a+b], a==b}
  }]
```

Option 3 : [Which](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html?q=Which)

```
Which[
  a>b,Sin[a-b],
  a<b,Tan[a/b]
  a==b,Cos[a+b]
]
```

Option 4 : [If](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)

```
If[a>b,
  Sin[a-b],
  IF[a<b,Tan[a/b], Cos[a+b]]
]
```

I left out options [Pattern test](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)(?), [Switch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html), [Boole](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) and others that are derived from them, like [Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [Except](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html)...

---

As personal preference I tend to use option 2 and Boole. If you ask why Boole then I would answer :

```
 PiecewiseExpand[Boole[a]]
```

[image]

There are more then 1 reason I do this, but mostly they are named in manual under details.