# Multi-case function: many single-case delayed assignments; or one Which[]?

Tags: function-construction

A function needs to cope with many different forms of input, such as different heads (`Plus`, `Times`, `Power`, etc). Should the function be defined with multiple Mathematica delayed assignments (such as “`PostScriptForm[Times[-1, thing_]] := …`”) or with one large assignment, likely to be of the form `PostScriptForm[thing_] := Which[ MatchQ[…], …, MatchQ[…], …, ]`?

If the context helps, it is about [`PostScriptForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101954/looking-for-postscriptform-or-forthform-to-print-expressions-as-rpn-code), which converts to PostScript as `CForm` converts to C.

Either form could work: which is more natural idiomatic Mathematica?

Edit: a related question. If multiple statements, as recommended in @eldo’s answer, should the statements be in different cells, or in the same cell separated by a blank line, or in the same cell without separations? Again, which is more natural idiomatic Mathematica?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(60846)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60846/121)

Comment: By the I addressed the performance issue in [(2618)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2618/121) and I agree with eldo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually prefer multiple function definitions. I find they are clearer to read, and they are usually faster, especially if you can avoid conditions, i.e. `f[1] := ...` is better than `f[x_] /; x == 1 ...`

```
Clear[f, g]

f[1] := 2
f[2] := 3
f[3] := 4
f[x_] := x

g[x_] := Switch[x, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, _, x]

f /@ Range[10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.109200

```
g /@ Range[10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.280801

Comment: Is the speed ordering general over most multi-case functions? I.e., have you previously tested some less-simple actual functions, with the same result? But, to argue the other possibility, would it be tidier to keep a function together and in one place by `Which` or `Switch`?

Comment: Question edited to add a sub-question to your answer.